# XOR neural network not converging with python implementation

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to deal with neural networks, but I'm very new to this. I've never understood the different implementations I found.

So I tried to make a simple **implementation of the XOR problem** with a MultiLayer Perceptron and backpropagation according to the book of Virginie MATHIVET, but my algorithm is **not converging**. I tried a lot of things but the result does not change. Here is my code:

```
class Neuron:

    def __init__(self, nb_inputs, bias):
        self.nb_inputs = nb_inputs
        self.bias = bias
        self.weights = [random()*2.0-1 for _ in range(nb_inputs+1)]
        self.deltas = [0.0 for _ in range(nb_inputs+1)]
        self.output = None

    def init_deltas(self):
        self.deltas = [0.0 for _ in range(self.nb_inputs+1)]

    def aggregation(self, inputs):
        return sum([self.weights[i] * inputs[i] for i in range(self.nb_inputs)]) + self.bias * self.weights[self.nb_inputs]

    def activation(self, value):
        return 1.0/(1.0+math.exp(-value))

    def compute_output(self, inputs):
        self.output = self.activation(self.aggregation(inputs))
        return self.output

class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, nb_inputs, nb_hidden, nb_outputs, learning_rate):
        self.nb_inputs = nb_inputs
        self.nb_hidden = nb_hidden
        self.nb_outputs = nb_outputs
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        self.output_layer = [Neuron(self.nb_hidden, 1.0) for _ in range(self.nb_outputs)]
        self.hidden_layer = [Neuron(self.nb_inputs, 1.0) for _ in range(self.nb_hidden)]

    def compute_outputs(self, inputs):
        hidden_outputs = [neuron.compute_output(inputs) for neuron in self.hidden_layer]
        outputs = [neuron.compute_output(hidden_outputs) for neuron in self.output_layer]
        return outputs[0]

    def init_deltas(self):
        for neuron in self.output_layer + self.hidden_layer:
            neuron.init_deltas()

    def train(self, data, nb_iterations):
        for _ in range(nb_iterations):
            self.init_deltas()

            for inputs in data:
                si, yi = self.compute_outputs(inputs), data[inputs]
                print si, yi
                # For each output neuron
                for neuron in self.output_layer:
                    # For each weight
                    for i in range(neuron.nb_inputs):
                        neuron.deltas[i] = si * (1 - si) * (yi - si)

                # For each hidden neuron
                for i in range(self.nb_hidden):
                    hidden_neuron = self.hidden_layer[i]
                    # For each weight
                    for k in range(hidden_neuron.nb_inputs):
                        total = 0.0
                        # For each output neuron
                        for output_neuron in self.output_layer:
                            total += output_neuron.deltas[i] * output_neuron.weights[i]
                        hidden_neuron.deltas[k] = hidden_neuron.output * (1 - hidden_neuron.output) * total

                # adjust weights in output_layer
                for neuron in self.output_layer:
                    for i in range(self.nb_hidden):
                        neuron.weights[i] += self.learning_rate * neuron.deltas[i] * neuron.output
                    neuron.weights[self.nb_hidden] += self.learning_rate * neuron.deltas[self.nb_hidden] * neuron.bias

                # adjust weights in hidden_layer
                for neuron in self.hidden_layer:
                    for i in range(self.nb_inputs):
                        neuron.weights[i] += self.learning_rate * neuron.deltas[i] * neuron.output
                    neuron.weights[self.nb_inputs] += self.learning_rate * neuron.deltas[self.nb_inputs] * neuron.bias

    def predict(self, inputs):
        return self.compute_outputs(inputs)
```

And to test it:

```
DATA = {
    (0, 0): 0,
    (1, 0): 1,
    (0, 1): 1,
    (1, 1): 0
}
nn = NeuralNetwork(2, 3, 1, 0.2)
nn.train(DATA, 50000)
nn.predict([0,0])
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I don't now, if this is problem. But learning rate is so high and iterations too low. Try 0.2 and 50 000...

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried it but the algorithm seems completely diverging... I've put 10 iterations for debugging purpose, I forget to replace it. 50.000 iterations and 0.2 learning rate does not change anything, the results are random

Comment: My suggestion is that you try to use NumPy and rewrite your code with matrix-based operations. It will be easier to understand and debug, as your code will be closer to how the equations look like. Otherwise, you may not find anybody willing to debug your code, as it is a tedious task. ;-)

Comment: Testing might help you debug too. Create tests to verify your code behaves as expected (i.e.: manually set inputs for your methods and check that the output is the expected in all methods).

Comment: Thanks, I will try both !